# Class has no field or association

Tags: symfony

Can someone help me with this please. I keep getting this error and I'm not sure why. [Semantical Error] line 0, col 75 near 'startDate AS': Error: Class com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Payrollperiod has no field or association named startDate. Even after I have changed it to correct name and clear the cache.

```
 public function getAllActivePayrollPeriods($em) {
//        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod');
        $payrollperiods = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->orderBy('p.startdate', 'ASC')
                        ->getQuery()->getResult();

        return $payrollperiods;
    }
```

**Entity**

```
private $startdate;
public function getStartdate() {
        return $this->startdate;
    }

     public function setStartdate(\DateTime $startdate) {
        $this->startdate = $startdate;
    }
```

Comment: Include your entity configuration in the question, right now we can't tell how your entity is mapped to Doctrine, it will probably be in `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine`

Answer (score 0):

The `$startdate` is not mapped to the entity.

Try to add a row to the XML:

```
<field name="startdate" type="datetime" column="startdate" nullable="false"/>
```

Then regenerate your entities and update your database schema.
Symfony3:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Symfony2:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I find it easier to use annotations for mapping so you can work in the same file.

Comment: Sure. Or yaml files. Regards

Comment: It is a query that's giving the issue not the mapping

Comment: Check startDate with D capital letter. Could be that? Regards

Comment: @Sue if your mapping is not correct your query will fail too offcourse. Also the error says startDate while the property in your entity is called startdate (lower case).